# Dart & InteliJ: Sort parameter order

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

Is there a script for Dart and IntelliJ which sorts the order of the parameters in methods and constructors?

For example I have this class:

```
MyClass {
  MyClass({this.para1, this.para2});
  int? para1;
  int? para2;
}
```

And I call the constructor like this.:

```
MyClass(para2: 2, para1: 1);
```

I would like to have a script which alters the code to:

```
MyClass(para1: 1, para2: 2);
```

So that the order of the parameters matches.

Comment: you cannot use `MyClass(true, 0);` since it has two named parameters, more here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. I updated my question.